# How to split an array in advanced for loop - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having an issue with splitting part of an array in python, here's the code that should split it:

```py
for meteor in meteor_pos:
    meteor_split = str(meteor.split(", "))
    player_split = str(player_pos.split(", "))
    if meteor_split[0] == player_split[0]:
        if meteor_split[1] == player_split[1]:
            return True
```

Here's the array when it's printed:

```
> player pos:  [400.0, 500] 
> 
> meteor pos: [[740, 161.0], [740, 117.0], [520, 102.0], [700, 86.0],
> [80, 76.0], [340, 39.0], [280, 10.0]]
```

I'm trying to split the X and Y values of each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanna check if list 1 is present in list 2 then you don't need a for loop for this -

```
def check_pos(player_pos,meteor_pos):
    return (player_pos in meteor_pos)

check_pos(player_pos,meteor_pos)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you converting meteor_split to a string? meteor should already be a list based on what you show for meteor_pos and player_pos. You should be able to just do meteor[0] and get the X value for meteor  in your for loop and the same goes for player_pos.